# Multiple String Inputs - Python

Tags: python, string, input

I'm new to coding and can't seem to figure out the issue with my code. So, I've created a variable. Now I am trying to use that variable in a string input, but I keep getting a

> TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3.

Any help would be appreciated!

E.g.

```
import random
number = random.randint(1,100)
random = str(input('Is', number, 'a prime number? '))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` method waits for one string, one that you need to build, here are ways (also it already returns a `string`, remove the `str`)

```
# f-string
random = input(f'Is {number} a prime number? ')

random = input('Is %s a prime number?' % number )
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `random = str(input('Is', number, 'a prime number? '))` with `random = str(input(f'Is {number}, a prime number? '))` since `input` takes 1 string. (Requires Python 3.6 and above)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
number = random.randint(1, 100)

random = str(input('Is ' + str(number) + ' a prime number? '))
```

Comment: Okey, I will put a text :)

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function takes only one argument, as the error message indicates, the string to display as a prompt, unlike the `print` function that can take multiple arguments. What you need to do is to combine all arguments in a single string. There are multiple ways to do it:

```py
# string concatenation
random = input('Is ' + str(number) + ' a prime number? ')

# string formatting
random = input('Is %d a prime number?' % number)

# f-strings
random = input(f'Is {number} a prime number?')
```